# How to add album covers for all MP3s in a folder with one click?

Tags: windows-10, mp3, album-art

Does Windows Media Player maybe do it?

Windows 10 64 V1903 and another PC V1803.

A free software that does this clicking song by song but is buggy:

https://www.creevity.com/mp3coverdownloader/

I tried BlissHQ but was complicated and didn't even do my free 100 MP3s fixes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Windows Media Player will do it if it can figure out what song it is dealing with.

It will *probably* need to move the files around so that they are grouped by artist/album at the same time.  I am not sure.  I never lump hundreds of MP3s into the same folder.

It will also update tag info so it is correct and optionally move fixed stuff to another folder so you know that it has modified it.

You need to go to:
***File->Manage Libraries->Music*** and add the root of folders you want in the library (aka want art for).

For anything it can find..

- the mp3 tags will get modified to contain year, artist, etc etc..
- It will download several tiny jpg files for album art to include one called Folder.jpg (this is a standard).  Folder.jpg is one of the MANY reasons you should allow it to categorize your mp3s by folder.

For anything it CANT find..

- Open the generic music icon in the player to the album view
- Right click on the music note and select "find album info" and it will give you a list of possible options.

Anything that knows about folder.jpg files should be able to display your art.  Explorer will do it.  Zune player, Media Player, Kodi, ... whatever.

***You will see the artwork filling in as it goes.***

Here is a screenshot of a folder in my library.  I didn't download or hand tweak any of this.

***From the windows explorer***
[image]

Also.. it is slow. Be patient. It will work.

Comment: Thx, but will it do it for a whole 650 songs folder (most with correct names) in one click? how? and will the files be changed in File Explorer or WMP only?

Comment: Yes, I have used it to DL art work for far more than 650 song.  If I understand "in one click" correctly.. yes, it will just do it for you in the background after you add a media library for music.  Just leave it running and minimize it.

Comment: I want my MP3 files in File Explorer, to show the pics of the cover album of the song, I use WMP since years and I added the folder of music and I don't see files changing their display pic in thumbnails of Win 10. Actually I added the folder yesterday, how much time should I wait?

Comment: Sorry.. until it is done.  Watch the media player library view to see what it is doing.  I have updated the answer above to show you a screen shot of the holy grail. :)

Comment: Thx, I don't have albums, I have single songs from many different albums, so I can understand it couldn't detect  the song name and artist from the name of the file, because I don't have them in the details of the file... how much time should I be patient? I added some pics using Creevity software and it's so buggy and I had to rename them and delete some duplicates created, and not always the right pic appears in WMP when playing a song, I want these pics to be corrected by WMP, how to do that?

Comment: I think I needed to change some checkboxes and a radiobutton in right click and Options-> Library, I will see if now it's gonna change...

Comment: It's terrible: For example it changed the song :"Inna Hot" to "01 Hot", I unchecked the box that it changes the names, but it didn't download any album covers. I'm rolling back a to saved backup...

Comment: @John1.. Then don't use it and don't give me any credit for trying to help you for free.  You are welcome.

Comment: I'm trying to see if wmp can help, thx a lot for helping me, I just want info regarding what wmp can do, I left it on all night with some songs with Title and Artists set in the details of the file, it did change the name of some 7 files but it didn't add album covers, I unchecked the change name option, why didn't it download album covers? Is there a setting I need to change?

Comment: Right click on any one song or album that it didn't find a cover for.  Choose "find album info".  You can at least pick from a list or see that it just can't figure it out.

Comment: It doesn't show all songs, I think I will stick to the buggy Creevity app and do them one by one.

Comment: Nothing is perfect.  Good luck!